# Output switching when re-arranging IF statement in Powershell

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I am trying to write a script that tests the connection of computers in an OU and then tells me if they are on or off. This is going to be included in a script that has the end function of testing the connection, and if the computer is turned on, then performing a regedit but if it is turned off just skipping the computer and moving to the next one. However I am having trouble with the first bit of my If statement.

```
ForEach ($computer in $ADComputers)
{$TestConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet

    If ($TestConnection -eq 'True')
        {Write-Host "$computer is on"}
            Else 
                {Write-Host "$computer is off"}}
```

This code block returns the following results, which are correct

```
MS04D4C492C172 is on
MS04D4C492BADB is on
MS04D4C4AAE3F2 is on
MS04D4C492BAE2 is off
```

However doing it in the reverse will be easier for my syntax with the rest of the script that I wish to create, but if I try the following

```
ForEach ($computer in $ADComputers)
{$TestConnection = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet

    If ($TestConnection -eq 'False')
        {Write-Host "$computer is off"}
            Else 
                {Write-Host "$computer is on"}}
```

My results are switched and I get this

```
MS04D4C492C172 is off
MS04D4C492BADB is off
MS04D4C4AAE3F2 is off
MS04D4C492BAE2 is on
```

I have tried running test connections manually on two of the computers and I get the following results

```
PS H:\> Test-Connection -ComputerName ms04d4c492c172 -Quiet
True

PS H:\> Test-Connection -ComputerName MS04D4C492BAE2 -Quiet
False
```

I don't understand why my output is switching. All I am doing is changing it from an if true to an if false statement? or am I doing something really silly here?

Comment: *"However doing it in the reverse will be easier for my syntax with the rest of the script"* - That makes no sense. Why would it be any easier if you swap the if?

Comment: Tomalak - I believe it would make it easier for my thought process of my script, I tried doing it the other way but I kept getting lost in my coding and thought that if I switched it around it would be easier for me to follow and troubleshoot. I might be wrong, I admit I am a bit of a noob but I am still confused as to why switching the true and false around like this produces opposite results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing to the *string* `'False'`. `Test-Connection -Quiet` gives you a *boolean* value. Powershell's booleans are `$true` and `$false`. Only when printed out they are displayed as `True` and `False`. But still, `$false` and `'False'` are different things.

If you use better variable names (`$isOnline` instead of `$testConnection`), and coherent indentation:

```
foreach ($computer in $ADComputers) {
    $isOnline = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet
    if ($isOnline) {
        Write-Host "$computer is on"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$computer is off"
    }
}
```

and then compare against an actual boolean value...

```
foreach ($computer in $ADComputers) {
    $isOnline = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet
    if ($isOnline -eq $false) {
        Write-Host "$computer is off"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$computer is on"
    }
}
```

**BUT**: Things like `if ($booleanValue -eq $true)` or `if ($booleanValue -eq $false)` are bad style.

The boolean value *already is* true or false. It's completely useless to compare it again. Therefore it's better written as `if ($booleanValue)` or `if (-not $booleanValue)`, and it also is a lot more readable that way:

```
foreach ($computer in $ADComputers) {
    $isOnline = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Quiet
    if (-not $isOnline) {
        Write-Host "$computer is off"
    } else {
        Write-Host "$computer is on"
    }
}
```